# Sum Distinct Value in TextBox Reporting Services 2017

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

Im trying to sum distinct value in SSRS 2017 in TExtbox 
and getting this error. i"m new in SSRS so please any one help me out

```
The Value expression for the text box ‘Textbox14’ uses an aggregate 
 expression without a scope.  A scope is required for all aggregates used 
  outside of a data region unless the report contains exactly one dataset.
```

my Expression is

```
=sum(Max(Fields!NumberPopuDefult.Value, "DataSet1"))
```

And i tried this expression as well

```
 =sum(Max(Fields!NumberPopuDefult.Value), "DataSet1")
```

getting same error

if any one know where I'm wrong.

Comment: Any one /................

Comment: any one plz ?????????????

Answer (score 0):

Your "DataSet1" needs to have a select distinct NumberPopuDefult clause and then amend your expression to be =sum(Fields!NumberPopuDefult.Value, "DataSet1")

Answer (score 0):

> A scope is required for all aggregates.

I see 2 aggregates: Max and Sum.  I see 1 scope: "Dataset1".  I suspect you're missing another scope.

So the syntax may be something similar to:

`=sum(Max(Fields!NumberPopuDefult.Value, "DataSet1"), "DataSet1")`

Otherwise, you could also try getting rid of one of the aggregates...

Comment: getting this error now

The Value expression for the text box ‘Textbox71’ has an inner aggregate in an outer aggregate that specifies a dataset scope.  An aggregate that specifies a dataset scope cannot contain other aggregates.